# Silverlight 4.0 : How to get DatagridTemplateColumn Header in code behind

Tags: silverlight-4.0, datagrid, header, datagridtemplatecolumn

have in XAML a datagridtemplate column

```
<sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn x:Name="Urgency">
                <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                            <Image Source="{Binding UrgencyUri}" 
                            VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                            Stretch="UniformToFill"
                            Height="10" Width="10" Margin="0,0,5,0"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Urgency}"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="primitive:DataGridColumnHeader">
                        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
                        <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Urgency, Source={StaticResource MHVWindowResources}}" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
                                        <filter:DataGridColumnFilter Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Right" />
                                    </Grid>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Style>
                </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderStyle>
            </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

I used this code below however it returns null

```
DataGridTemplateColumn templateColumn = dataGrid.Columns[columnIndex] as DataGridTemplateColumn;
            if (templateColumn != null)
            {

                string header = templateColumn.Header as string;

                if (header == null)
                {
                    return null;
                }
                bindingPath = header;
            }
```

Is their anything that I missed out? Thanks
I want to know how to get the column header in code behind.

Comment: i guess this is because your TextBlock is defined in the HeaderStyle level not in the Header level.

Answer (score 0):

Add this line:

```
 var header = templateColumn.Header
```

place a break point here debug and check what the type is in the quick watch.

My bet is the header is probably never a string so it always null when you use:

```
string header = templateColumn.Header as string;
```

hope that helps